# uploadprogress.so for PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, pecl

I'm using XAMPP (latest version) on OS 10.6.2, that's bundled with PHP 5.3.0

I installed the XAMPP development package for the PHP source/header files and ran the following command from Terminal-

```
sudo ./pecl install uploadprogress
```

Everything appeared to work fine. My php.ini file (*yup* - I checked it's the same one being loaded in `phpinfo()`) has the `extension=uploadprogress.so` in there fine, and I restarted apache via:

```
sudo ./apachectl restart
```

... under my xamppfiles/bin directory.

The issue is, the uploadprogress extension is not shown on `phpinfo()`.

I can't think what I'm missing. I didn't get an Apache/PHP restart errors stating the extension couldn't be loaded, or is incompatible or anything.

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE--***

I fixed the problem. It was the Snow Leopard 64bit compile flags that needed adding to the configure line!

For the information of anyone who finds themselves in this scenario, these are the exact steps performed-

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/uploadprogress-1.0.1.tgz

tar zxvf uploadprogress-1.0.1.tgz

cd uploadprogress-1.0.1.tgz

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize-5.3.0

MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6 CFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64' LDFLAGS='-O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64' CXXFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64' ./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config-5.3.0

make

sudo make install
```

Then edit */Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini* and make sure the following is added somewhere:

```
extension=uploadprogress.so
```

Restart Apache and *voila*, it worked. Yay.

Comment: how do you know what values to put on the FLAGS ?

Comment: Google - found an example of compiling other libraries on a 64bit Mac, and simply swiped that

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed @Lee's solution works on Mac OSX Lion (10.7.3) + XAMPP 1.7.3 (with developer packaged installed). Only change is php on XAMPP has been upgraded so where he uses "5.3.0" — change to "5.3.1"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need APC enabled in order for this to work.

Try enabling the extension in your php.ini and see if that fixes it!

Comment: Thanks Alex- I actually had to compile APC from source before enabling it, using the same compile flags I've updated in the solution above, since I was using Snow Leopard and 64-bit installation. Took me a lot of searching to discover that- tried compiling using `pecl` too, and that didn't work. Anyone who needs APC first (I had them both installed by the time I got this working, so I couldn't tell if APC was definitely needed or not), compile using the instructions above but replace uploadprogress with the APC package. Do a google search to find it on PECL.